# Trying to write a sorting program with ruby - stack level too deep (system stack error)

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow

I'm reading Chris Pine's book "Learn to Progam" (it's about Ruby). Right now I'm trying to write a program that sorts words. Unfortunately I'm stuck with: `stack level too deep (system stack error) in line 16`, which, if i Googled correctly means that there is an infinite loop, but I don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
words = []
wordss = []
word = 'word'
i = 0
k = 0

def sortw array
  i = 0
  if    (array.length == 1) || (array.length == 0)
  else sort array, [], [], i
  end
  return array
end

def sort unsorted, unsort, sorted, i
  k = 0 # The error should be here, according to command prompt
  while i < unsorted.length

    while (unsorted[i] < unsorted[k])
      if    k < unsorted.length
        k = k + 1
      elsif k == unsorted.length
        sorted.push unsorted[i]
      else unsort.push unsorted[i]
      end
    end

    i = i + 1
    sort unsorted, unsort, sorted, i
  end

  if unsort.length != 1
    i = 0
    sort unsort, [], sorted, i
  else sorted.push unsort[0]
  end

  return sorted
end

puts 'type one word per line...'
puts 'typing enter on an empty line sorts the inputted words'

while word != ''
  word = gets.chomp
  words = words.push word
end

wordss = (sortw words)

puts 'your words'
puts words
puts 'sorted here'
puts wordss
```

Comment: What version of Ruby? I can run the code just fine in the IRB using version 1.9.2.

Comment: 1.9.2. At first the code runs fine, but after 'gets'-ing words and giving the go to sort them, the system track error occurs.

Comment: @yoeh Ah... was able to recreate now.

Comment: i forgot to change german lines into english ones...can't find an edit-button...it says: type one word per line...enter on an empty line sorts the inputed words

Comment: Are you sure `wordss` and `sortw` are good names?

Comment: kind of...yes...wordss = words sorted, sortw = sort wrapped...do you disagree? if so, why? btw: thanks for editing my question! (this thanks goes to the both of you...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because recursion does not stop due to a problem with the sorting algorithm. In the `sort` method, `k` is always less than `unsorted.length`. This causes the other arrays, `sorted` and `unsort` to never populate.

For example try these for input:

- dog
- zebra
- cat

Additionally, I think you want to not include the blank line so I would change the code from:

`words = words.push word` to `words = words.push word if word != ''`

This creates the `unsorted` array:

- [0] dog
- [1] zebra
- [2] cat

Numbered below are the iterations of the recursive `sort` method.

```
#initial variable state:
i = 0
k = 1
```

1. dog = dog

   - skip second while loop
   - i = 1
2. zebra > dog

   - skip second while loop
   - i = 2
3. cat < dog

   - enter second while loop

     - k = 1, now cat < zebra, so keep looping
     - k = 2, now cat = cat, so exit while
   - i = 3
4. Since `i` is now equal to the `unsorted` array length, the two while loops never get entered anymore.

Therefore, the following code results in an infinite loop since nothing was pushed to the `unsort` array:

```
if unsort.length != 1
  i = 0
  sort unsort, [], sorted, i #Problem is that `unsort` and `sorted` are empty
elsif
...
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot! ymmd! i can now see the problem...i tried to fix it, but i get the same error over and over again...i think i have to rewrite the whole thing

Comment: @yoeh: Glad to help! I wanted to help you see what was wrong instead of fixing it. As an FYI, I realize you are writing the code in order to learn, and it's fun writing algorithms, but there is a sort function for arrays already in Ruby (I'm sure you already know). To do this idiomatically, you would just say: `unsorted = ['dog', 'zebra', 'cat']`
`sorted = unsorted.sort`

Comment: yes, i know about the sort method for arrays and yes, you're right, i try to write my own code to learn. i'm also thankful that you just pointed out the error instead of fixing it...as i said, i'm trying to learn something :)